# Changing padding values in a shape inside a layer-list resource programmatically

Tags: java, android, padding, layer-list

I use this xml resource, with padding

```
<item android:id="@+id/first_image">
    <shape
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:left = "1dp"
        android:right = "50dp"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="10dp"
            android:color="@color/orange_dd" />

        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="99dp"
            android:top="1dp" />           
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/second_image">
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle" 
        android:left = "200dp"
        android:right = "440dp"
        >
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="@color/turquesa_l"
            android:endColor="@color/turquesa_l"
            android:startColor="@color/turquesa_ddd" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I want to change programmatically the value of the right padding (value 99) to a different value. 
I know how to change other attributes of the shapes, like color, or radios, but didn't found how to change padding values...

Comment: why you want to change padding? means for different screen resolution support or any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the set padding method:

```
    Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setPadding(10,20,30,40);
```

the same should apply to shape too.
you can use `getPaddingLeft()`, `getPaddingTop()`, `getPaddingRight()` or `getPaddingBottom()` to get the other padding's value if you only want to change one of the 4 padding value.

more information about [setpadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method.